# Can I use drf-spectacular's GET_MOCK_REQUEST setting to fake a request when testing my API with Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

I'm using `drf-spectacular` to document the API endpoints of a Django / DRF project, mainly with the @extend_schema decorator and it works nicely for the Swagger UI.

What I would like to do is to "alter the behaviour" of some of the API endpoints so that *when they are called from Swagger UI*, we end up with a faked response of some sort (instead of regularly processing the request through the code).

So I'm trying things with the `GET_MOCK_REQUEST` setting, but I can't get anywhere :

- its **function** seems to be called once per detected endpoint during api schema generation called through URL `my-project/api-schema/` (but I can't see any changes in the yaml schema file, is this revealing ?).
- when playing with the supposed "altered endpoints" in Swagger UI, this **function** is not called.

I'm probably missing something here, I might have misunderstood what `GET_MOCK_REQUEST` is meant for...

Some help would be appreciated.